# Multiple vertically scrolling UIScrollViews in a horizontal UIScrollView

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm developing an app, where I have one horizontally scrollable UIScrollView fullscreen with pagination that contains multiple (let's say 3) vertically scrollable UIScrollViews, each also fullscreen. They're positioned without margins, the left ones origin is (0,0).

Each vertically scrollable UIScrollView consists of buttons placed one above the other, each when clicked, presents a ViewController:

```
[self presentViewController:someViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now this code works fine for the two right UIScrollViews, but it's buggy for the left one:

- The buttons bellow the height of the horizontal UIScrollView are not clickable. So if the height of the horizontal UIScrollView is 440px, any UIButton with origin.y > 440 is uncklickable.
- If the UIScrollView is slightly scrolled down and a button is clicked (that is not below 440px), the whole UIScrollView gets "moved" down and gets sorta laggy while the requested view controller gets presented. When this view controller gets dismissed, the scroll view stays lower. If I scroll it back up and press a button, it magically jumps up to where it should be.

Now for the fun part!

If I change the origin of the left UIScrollView to (1,0), this issue dissapears! What could be making this problem?

Some added code:

```
[horizontalSV setDelegate:self];
[horizontalSV setContentSize:horizontalContentView.frame.size];
[horizontalSV addSubview:horizontalContentView];                  // View containing vertical scroll views, it's set up in IB
[horizontalContentView setFrame:CGRectMake(-1, 0, 961, 440)];     // This is now used for the hack

// Now imagine three of these
firstSVcontent = [[VerticalContentView alloc] init];              // Setting the content view
[firstSVcontent setTitle:title];
[firstSVcontent setButtons:blahblah];
[firstVerticalSV setContentSize:firstSVcontent.view.frame.size];  // Setting vertical scroll view
[firstVerticalSV addSubview:firstSVcontent.view];
```

Comment: OK, I've found a work around: make the view that contains the vertically scrollable UIScrollViews 1px wider and then make it's origin.x = -1.

But still, I'd like to see if someone knows what the hell is going on.

Comment: That seems hack-y. Can you paste some code?

Comment: @EliGregory And it unfortunatelly is. I added the setup code.

Comment: first make sure you have set up the horizonal scroll view correctly - here's a reliable tutorial: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/

Comment: At the moment, I am building an app like this as well. Mine also has horizontal scrolling w/ paging enabled and then vertical scrolling on the pages. It works well. I don't know why yours is working wrong, mostly because I can't see your code, though I am willing to offer advice.

Comment: It's set up correctly and I've dealt with UIScrollViews many times before but this is a first. Thanks for your input though, I'll try to make something from scratch and see if the problem persists. For now I'm quite happy with the hack, it works as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved this issue almost a year later!

The problem was, I was doing most of my view managment in a XIB file and then I just read those content views and scroll views in  my viewDidLoad method and put them together.

Now I've rewritten my code to create all scroll views and content views programatically and everything works without a problem.